# Facebook Share Screen does not appear

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to share an image using the following code,

however sometimes sharing screen does not appear.

it Happens very intermittently. Any idea whats causing this ?

When this happens app just navigates to Facebook app & the sharing scree does not show up.

```
if ([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:params]) {
         // Present share dialog
        FBAppCall *call = [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:params.link
                                          name:params.name
                                       caption:params.caption
                                   description:params.linkDescription
                                       picture:params.picture
                                   clientState:nil
                                       handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {

 }]; }
```

Comment: This seems like a similar issue,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684886/sometimes-the-facebook-share-dialog-doesnt-load-on-ios?rq=1

Comment: are you sure you are calling this from the main thread?

Answer (score 0):

Add below code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
          openURL:(NSURL *)url
sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
       annotation:(id)annotation {
return  [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication withSession:[FBSession activeSession] fallbackHandler:^(FBAppCall *call) {

}];
```

}

Hope this helps..

Comment: This is already there . The app navigates to Facebook app , but the sharing screen does not come up . This happens very rarely .