# Facebook App share dialog does not appear sometimes

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

Sometimes the share screen does not load on the Facebook App , when I try to share a picture from the iOS application. This happens when I try to share a picture after a long time and the second time onwards the share screen appears flawlessly.

When this happens the iOS app directs to the Facebook app , however the share screen does not appear. It just ends up on the newsfeed.

```
if ([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:params]) {
         // Present share dialog
        FBAppCall *call = [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:params.link
                                          name:params.name
                                       caption:params.caption
                                   description:params.linkDescription
                                       picture:params.picture
                                   clientState:nil
                                       handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {

 }]; }
```

Does anybody know what's causing this abrupt behavior?

Comment: This seems like a similar issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684886/sometimes-the-facebook-share-dialog-doesnt-load-on-ios?rq=1

Comment: Yeah that explains it  , but it does not provide a solution at all.

Answer (score 0):

Hey if your device dnt hv **Facebook** app then this block will not execute.. then you should handle your block of code into else part. using **Feed** scenario.....check it first

#### Modified

```
FBLinkShareParams *params = [[FBLinkShareParams alloc] init];
params.link = YOUR_URL;
params.picture=YOUR_PICTURE_URL;
params.name=NAME;
params.caption =YOUR_CAPTION_OR_DESCRIPTION;
params.linkDescription = DESCRIPTION_LINK;

// If the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog

if ([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:params])
{
    // Present share dialog
    [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:params.link handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error)
      {
           //Handle result and error....
      }];
}
else
{
    // FALLBACK: publish just a link using the Feed dialog
}
```

### This will work....

Comment: The Facebook app is installed in the device , the problem is sometimes the share screen does not get displayed first time  . It just opens the app with news feed. The second time onwards it works perfectly.